# Docker Container breaks after using bash shell script containing ssh

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

This may be a wordy one, so bear with me.

We run a Docker Container on our local Windows machines of our web application for development and testing. It all works beautifully and has for many years.

We have recently wanted to run a custom deployment shell script from our local Docker to clone our contents to whatever other server we want. Test, Production, etc.

After a few days of getting the SSH permissions setup on the Docker Desktop, we can now successfully run bash out of the Docker exec command window, and then I can run our deployment.sh script.

However, this is where the issue begins. The deployment shell script runs successfully, and then it can't do anything else. The shells script clones everything we need and finishes, and then...nothing.

I can't exactly give you all a stand alone reproducible example of two unix systems talking to each other via ssh, but I can give a simple shell snippet example:

```
for target in $targets; do 
   rsync *checks differences between target and local*
   read -p "Deploying to $target on $server. Continue with Sync? " -n 1 -r
   if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
      rsync *commands to clone my changed webapp content and exclude desired files*
   else 
      exit 
   fi
done
```

After this, I can't access my web application on our local host, I can't rerun any other scripts, and I can't even restart my container without an error:

`Cannot restart container exampleWebapp: tried to kill container, but did not receive an exit event`

I tried using "exit" in the exec commands, I tried composing down and rebuilding, and the only thing that 99% works is restarting the whole engine.

I have no idea what is locking everything up, and I have no idea how to just close out whatever lingering connection it has with the SSH to just get the environment back to when I "start" the container.

While restarting the engine isn't the end of the world, it really slows down our workflow, and I've even had the engine restart not resolve this a few times.

Here's something else to note. We run this deployment.sh script in our apache based servers all the time with zero issue. It seems to be specific to running in this Docker VM unix environment, and I can't seem to find anything on Google or Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd be a little concerned about the `docker exec` workflow you describe here in general.  Anything you do via `docker exec` is intrinsically temporary, and will be lost as soon as the container is destroyed.  Docker-based workflows I'm more used to will build a new self-contained image, and replace the old container with a new one based on the new image; you shouldn't typically need a shell in a container to administer it.

Comment: hey @amphetamachine I have a small snippet of the shell script. The Dockerfile creates an apache2 server environment with all of the necessary modules and packages. The new addition to explore this deployment workflow was to mount my local ssh directory, run my key scan, for known hosts, and run a permission set.  Which all seems to be working without issue. No warnings. No failures.

Comment: You're asking the user for input in an automated script, that's why it's hanging.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps? So that shell script for loop runs for each server specified. The Docker Desktop Exec command window allows the user to enter an input. So I was able to successfully put "y" to continue the rsync process. I was getting the window to tell me each server name. So server 1, server 2, server 3, etc. The loop seemed to stop after it reached the final server. Is there any command on my end I can run to try and quit the script, if it happens to still be running? I could at least test that and see if it does anything. I'll look on my end and get back to you.